# "everyone", "everybody", "everything", and "everywhere" - singular or plural.

Tags: grammatical-number, any-every

Are "everyone", "everybody", "everything", and "everywhere" singular or plural.

I have found people who are say they are singular but also people who say they are plural. 
I can anyone give me an explanation?

Thank you

Comment: they're all singular - i'm not the best person to explain why other than saying that's just the way the language is.

Comment: Collective nouns are generally treated as singular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are all [singular indefinite pronouns](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/sv_agr.htm). The ones you listed are always singular. However, there are three indefinite pronouns that can be singular or plural, depending on the context: *all*, *some*, and *none*. These depend on whether what you're using them with is singular or plural. For example:

All the pie **is** gone.
All the pieces of pie **are** gone.

Some of the pie **is** gone.
Some of the pieces of pie **are** gone.

None of the pie **is** gone.
None of the pieces of pie **are** gone.

Maybe it was these indefinite pronouns that people were referring to when they said they could be plural. But the ones you listed, along with others such as *somebody*, *nobody*, *each*, and *every*, are always singular.

Comment: These are actually [_Quantifiers_](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/116684/15299) combined with indefinite pronouns, and [quantifier syntax is rather complex](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/73985/15299). As you point out, _all_ with count nouns is plural, while _each_ and _every_ are singular.