# Is "each" an adverb, pronoun, determiner, or what else?

Tags: adverbs, pronouns, determiners, parts-of-speech

**What do Online Dictionaries Say?**

[Cambridge Dictionaries Online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/american-english/each) says *each* is used as an **adverb** in the following examples:

> There are five leaflets – please take one of *each*.
> *Each* of the brothers has a different personality.
> It’s 500 miles *each* way.
> The bill comes to $80, so that’s $20 *each*

[Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/each) says *each* is a **determiner** and a **pronoun** in the following

> *each one* of us was asked what went on (determiner)
> Derek had money from *each* of his five uncles (pronoun)

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/each)'s entry for *each* states it is an **adjective**,

> A rope was tied to *each* end of the boat.
> *Each* student had a different explanation.

a **pronoun**,

> He took shot after shot, *each* missing by inches

and an **adverb**

> They cost 50 cents *each*.
> We were allowed two tries *each*.

But [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinite_pronoun) tells me that *each* is an **indefinite pronoun**

> Each of the players has a doctor

and [Grammar Monster](http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/indefinite_adjectives.htm) (which btw I really like) says that *each* is an **indefinite adjective**

> An indefinite adjective is used to describe a noun in a non-specific
> sense.
>
> The most common indefinite adjectives are: any, **each**, few, many, much,
> most, several, and some.
> They are often used to describe a noun to show an element of uncertainty.
>
> Indefinite adjectives should not be confused with indefinite pronouns. **Indefinite adjectives modify nouns or pronouns**. Indefinite pronouns are standalone pronouns

---

**Examples**

1. I gave my friends a book **each**
2. I gave **each** a book
3. I gave **each of** my three friends a book
4. I gave a book to **each one of** my friends
5. **Each one of** my friends received a book
6. **Each** friend of mine received a book

I believe that all the sentences above are grammatical. If any are considered non-standard in English, please please tell me!

### QUESTIONS

- For sentence No. 1, I cannot find a satisfying "tag" to place on *each*. Since the word "each" is placed at the end of a sentence, I suppose it must be an adverb but it feels like a quantifier to me because it tell me *how many* books, i.e. *to each of my friends*. Is *each* in No.1 an adverb? Why?
- Sentence 2 is definitely a pronoun.
- For sentences 3, 4, and 5 "each of" and "each one of" can be substituted with ***all of***, with no loss in meaning. But are *each of* and *each one of* pronouns? If we use a *pronoun* to replace a noun phrase or a noun, then how can *each* in: ***each (one) of my friends*** be a pronoun? And I imagine it can't be an *indefinite pronoun* because we know exactly "how many" people in sentence 3. Oxford Dictionaries suggest that *each of* is a pronoun but *each one of* is a determiner.
- In sentence 6 *each* is an adjective/determiner/indefinite adjective because it tells us something about the number of friends. *Right*?

Comment: Your six sentences are fine, grammatical and otherwise unexceptionable. Why are you worried? The only slight grating on my ear might be #1 (I probably would prefer to say "a book *apiece*" there) but that is my own idiosyncrasy.

Comment: @Robusto  I'm preparing a handout for a private student, and I wanted to double-check. It's really the POS that's bothering me. Some students *demand* to know the classification of a word, and this is one of them.  Thanks for swift reply :)

Comment: of each, adverb???

Comment: @TRomano Yes, three question marks. :) :) :) Exactly how I felt while trying to decipher which is which.

Comment: I'd go with Oxford and M-W.  I don't know *what* they've been imbibing, ingesting, smoking, or injecting down in the fenlands. One could say "one of each" specifies the *manner* of taking, and is hence an adverbial phrase.  But function and POS aren't the same.

Comment: "If we use a pronoun to replace a noun phrase or a noun, then how can each (one) of my friends be a pronoun?" -- Here, "each" is a determiner and is left behind when a noun ("one" or "friend") has been dropped.  There are other such constructions, where a determiner "some"/"any"/"his" remains behind when a noun is left understood.

Comment: For your student who demands POS, I've seen "FQ", for "floated quantifier", used for the "each" that means the same as the determiner "each" but turns up in some sort of adverb position.

Comment: It might be helpful, prior to embarking on classifying POS's (what's the plural, anyway?), to have some pool to choose from (one can probably go into various levels of detail).

Comment: John Lawler says "Quantifier." http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/116662/each-pronoun-or-adverb

Comment: @ScotM What always? Or in No. 3, 4 and 5

Comment: His answer **seems** to indicate that "Qunatifier" is the best way to think about *each* as a POS, and that its formulations are variations on the "quantifier theme". This idea of Q-float seems particularly useful for your question about #1, which seems to shift "each" from the prenominal position in "***each of*** my friends" to an adverbial position. In fact, each of your six sentences are a variation on the same "quantifier theme": **"each of my friends."**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a [related question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/116662/each-pronoun-or-adverb), John Lawler has suggested [Quantifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantifier_(linguistics)) as the designation for *each*:

> In linguistics and grammar, a quantifier is a type of **determiner**, such
>   as *all*, *some*, *many*, *few*, *a lot*, and *no*, (but not
>   numerals)... that indicates quantity.

The Wikipedia article recognizes the difficulty of analyzing quantifiers in natural language:

> The study of quantification in natural languages is much more
>   difficult than the corresponding problem for formal languages. This
>   comes in part from the fact that **the grammatical structure of natural
>   language sentences may conceal the logical structure**. Moreover,
>   mathematical conventions strictly specify the range of validity for
>   formal language quantifiers; for natural language, specifying the
>   range of validity requires dealing with non-trivial semantic problems.
>   For example the sentence "Someone gets mugged in New York every 10
>   minutes" does not identify whether it is the same person getting
>   mugged every 10 minutes....

Each of the six sentences in the OP share a **common logical meaning**:

> Y received a book
>
> Where Y is the quantified group: ***each of my friends***.

In the first four sentences, the **agent** is identified with the active voice of ***give***, while the identity of the **agent** is suppressed in the passive euivalent of ***receive*** for sentences 5-6. Additionally, each sentence adds or reduces identifying information without changing the **common logical meaning** of the sentence, but in doing this changes the interaction of the words and phrases.

> 1. I gave my friends a book each.

This is the **logical equivalent** to: *I gave each of my friends a book*, where:

- *gave* is the transitive verb
- *I* is the agent of the action
- *a book* is the theme of the action
- *each of my friends* is the recipient

As John Lawler explained the **Q-float**: "each of my friends" is transformed, eliminating the *of* and moving each from its normal prenominal position into an *adverbial* position:

*I gave my friends a book each*, where:

- *gave* is the transitive verb
- *I* is the agent of the action
- *a book* is the theme of the action
- *my friends* is the recipient
- *each* identifies ambiguously with *gave* **or** *my friends*

It is ambiguous because *each* has floated to the end of the sentence, but one can reasonably parse *each* as an **adverb**. "The grammatical structure conceals the logical structure" slightly, but the natural reader, who rarely bothers to parse consciously, can intuitively interpret the common logical meaning: *Each of my friends received a book,* with an added **emphasis** on *each*.

> 2. I gave each a book.

This is a much simpler analysis. *Each of my friends* is reduced to *each*, which is used as a **pronoun** recipient. Again the natural reader infers the common logical meaning: *Each of my friends received a book,* but they are probably expecting clearer identification in the larger context.

> 3. I gave each of my **three** friends a book.

Adding the extra modifier *three* does not change the **quantifier** function in this construction. It behaves like *all*, because *all* is also a quantifier. Because the phrase is reduced so naturally, *each* can be parsed as a **pronoun** recipient. Still the natural reader interprets the common meaning: *Each of my friends received a book,* with the additional information.

> 4. I gave a book to each one of my friends

Since [quantifiers](http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/determiners-and-quantifiers) are a type of determiner, this is simply adding one determiner to another along the lines of "any other". Again, the phrase is reduced so naturally, *each* is parsed routinely as a **pronoun**. The natural reader interprets the common meaning: *Each of my friends received a book,* with the additional emphasis of *each one*.

> 5. Each one of my friends received a book.

The shift to the passive equivalent "received" subdues the identity of the agent, emphasizing the theme and the recipient. Once again, the natural lister automatically gets it.

> 6. Each friend of mine received a book.

This construction is the clearest use of *each* as a quantifier, making it very easy to label it with the more general tag: **determiner**. *Each friend of mine* is the logical (and linguistic) equivalent to *each of my friends*, so the natural reader interprets the same common meaning: *Each of my friends received a book*.

**Conclusion:**

The grammatical usage of the quantifier *each* may change with different constructions, but each of the uses is logically connected to its function as a quantifier.

Comment: Thank you for making this sound relatively straightforward. I understood everything, which worries me because normally linguistics jargon confuses me :) Brill!

Comment: You may find it easy to understand, because I am not really fluent in linguistese, so I use it very sparingly.