# The function of all, both, and each

Tags: grammar, diagramming

These pronouns, which seem to behave the same way, confound me. I'm always scratching my head whenever I come across them in a diagram.

```
1) All the students can go. 
2) All of the students can go.
3) They all can go.
4) The students can all go.
```

These sentences *all* have the same semantic meaning, but what is the function of "all/both/each" in these examples?

Comment: That's because they're Quantifiers, not just pronouns. One thing that _all, both,_ and _each_ can do is appear in their normal position modifying a noun phrase, **or** appear in an adverbial position before the main verb or (after the first auxiliary verb if there is one). This rule is called ["Q-Float"](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/116684/15299). Only some quantifiers can float, however; _each_ and _all_ float, but _every_ and _any_ don't.

Comment: Huh? There is no occurrence of *both* or *each* in any of those examples.

Comment: @Drew Each and both function the same way. You can replace all with both or each in the examples, i.e "They can each go".

Answer (score 1):

In a comment, John Lawler wrote:

> That's because they're Quantifiers, not just pronouns. One thing that *all, both,* and *each* can do is appear in their normal position modifying a noun phrase, **or** appear in an adverbial position before the main verb or (after the first auxiliary verb if there is one). This rule is called ["Q-Float"](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/116684/15299). Only some quantifiers can float, however; *each* and *all* float, but *every* and *any* don't.