# It’s an insult to us each

Tags: pronouns, determiners, quantifiers

*The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (Pages 427-28) has this:

> **Universal personal pronouns of the type *us all*** 
> [6] i a. They’ve invited *us all*. b. It’s an insult to *us both*. 
> ii a. She likes *you all*. b. I’m counting on *you both* to help. 
> iii a. This applies to *them all*. b. I expect *them both* to take part. 
> Here we take *all* and *both* to be incorporated into a compound pronoun. These forms are to be distinguished from the sequences found in the much more general construction seen in:
> [7] i a. We *all*/*both* enjoyed it. b. We had *all*/*both* enjoyed it. 
> ii a. You *each* qualify for a prize. b. You will *each* qualify for a prize. 
> iii a. They *all five of them* complained. b. They are *all five of them* complaining. 
> In this construction the underlined expressions are quantificational adjuncts functioning in clause structure. This is evident from the fact that when the verb is an auxiliary they preferentially follow rather than precede it, as in the [b] examples. Note also the possibility of inserting an adjunct after the pronoun and before the quantificational adjunct in [a]: We certainly *all*/*both* enjoyed it. No such insertions are permitted in [6]: *She likes you certainly *all*. A further important difference is that in the adjunct construction the pronoun can be replaced by NPs with common noun heads: The girls *all*/*both* enjoyed it. Again, such replacements are quite impossible in [6]: *They’ve invited the girls *all*.
> The adjuncts in [7] have the form of fused-head NPs. As the examples show, the pattern extends beyond *all* and *both*, covering *each* and partitives that are excluded from [6]: *It’s an insult to us *each*, *This applies to them *all five of them*. The combinations in [6] are thus not predictable by any general rule, and are best regarded as compound forms; they are limited to the six accusative forms cited.

[6] describes six compound pronouns *us all*, *us both*, *you all*, *you both*, *them all*, and *them both*. And [7] describes fused-head NPs containing *all*, *both*, or *each*. Per CGEL, these NPs are quantificational adjuncts functioning in clause structure and are to be distinguished from compound pronouns.

CGEL says further that compound pronouns cannot have *each* as in *us each*, *you each*, *them each*. Hence, the ungrammatical **It’s an insult to us each*. But why can't *each* belong in [7] in *It’s an insult to us each*?

Here are some examples where *us each*, *you each*, or *them each* is used:

> The point is not really whether $200,000 is reasonable; it is that the very notion of attaching a dollar figure to an experience as momentous as parenthood is a sign of how much my mind-set has been warped by this system that leaves *us each* so very much on our own, able to avail ourselves of only what we can pay for. <[The New York Times, 2019](https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2019/11/16/opinion/sunday/capitalism-children.html)>

> All I need you to do is carve out two nights a week until the wedding to help. I’ll send *you each* a supplies list, and to make sure the cost distribution is fair, please send me a confidential email stating how much you earn — tax forms or pay stubs are fine. <[The New York Times, 2017](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/07/06/opinion/sunday/chill-bride.html)>

> It’s mid-May, it’s beautiful out, and your students are restless. One solution: Hand them The New York Times. 
> Next, ask *them each* to pick one article — any article, for any reason — read it, and tell us in the comments here why they chose it. <[The New York Times, 2018](https://www.nytimes.com/2018/05/10/learning/from-naked-museum-tours-to-ai-brains-17-times-articles-teenagers-recommend-right-now.html)>

If these are all fine, why isn't *It’s an insult to us each*?

Comment: I suspect it's relevant that this can occur as a (direct or indirect) object, but not as a complement of a preposition: "They gave us each some expensive gifts" is fine, but \* "They gave some expensive gifts to us each" is not, at least to my ear. If the "each" in the first of those is an adjunct, it's an odd one, since it isn't in any of the usual (front, central, or end) positions.

Comment: At the same time, "They insulted us each" sounds, if not wrong, very awkward. Hrm.

Comment: Also: "Ask them each to pick one article" and "Ask them each a question" both sound much better than "Ask them each" on its own.

Comment: (Then there's the construction "We gave the children one apple each." Hrm.)

Comment: @alphabet How about this one? _Everyone we meet is lovely – gentle, kind, sincere. It is hard not to warm to them each individually..._ https://www.theguardian.com/tv-and-radio/2023/feb/28/the-mormons-are-coming-review-lovely-kind-and-deeply-unsettling

Comment: I have a theory, but — your own examples aside — do you agree that *\*It’s an insult to us each* is incorrect?

Comment: @TinfoilHat Yes, I think it's ungrammatical. Please write up an answer.

Comment: It’s not an answer, really. Just an observation that *CGEL* hasn’t supplied any examples like yours in their [7]; you have objects instead of subjects. But: “…in the adjunct construction the pronoun can be replaced by NPs with common noun heads: *The girls all/both enjoyed it.*” So just replace the pronoun in your sentences with *the girls* to test. If it passes, you have an adjunct; if it doesn’t, you have “compound pronoun.” (Your examples pass, while *\*It’s an insult to us each* doesn’t.)

Comment: @TinfoilHat Does the Guardian example in the comment pass too? _It is hard not to warm to the girls each individually..._

Comment: It’s surely awkward and possibly redundant, but look into [John Lawler’s Q-Float](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/116662/each-pronoun-or-adverb): *Each of the boys said they would go.* == Q-Float ==> *The boys each said they would go.* Then yours: *It is hard not to warm to each of the girls individually.* == Q-Float ==> *It is hard not to warm to the girls each individually*...

Comment: @TinfoilHat I think it's more complicated than John Lawler made it out to be: "Like many quantifiers, however, _each_ is subject to a syntactic rule called "Quantifier Shift" (aka "Quantifier-Float" or "Q-Float"), which moves a quantifier from a prenominal position to an adverbial position. [...] Q-Float applies to the quantifier all as well as _each_, but not to the quantifier _every_".

Comment: @TinfoilHat For example, in _We are each and every one of us strangers in a strange land, but the Jews arrived at their promised destination._ (an NYT article), the entire NP _each and every one of us_, not "quantifiers", is in an adverbial position, and it's not even moved from a prenominal position either. *_Each and every one of us we are strangers in a strange land, but the Jews arrived at their promised destination._

Comment: @TinfoilHat And it's not even correct to say that you'd need either _all_ or _both_ or _each_ for "Quantifier Shift", as shown in this Washington Post article: _If you expect a musical about Jews and Arabs inevitably to be about unresolved hostility, then this one will broaden your perspective. Because surprise, surprise: We’re **every one of us** waiting in the desert for a little happiness._ https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/arts-and-entertainment/wp/2017/11/09/the-bands-visit-is-gentle-soulful-tuneful-and-the-best-new-musical-on-broadway/

Comment: Those are of the pattern in [7] iii b. *They are all five of them complaining.* And, by the way, I find *CGEL*’s example and your two as well to be odd for their lack of commas. cf. *They are, all five of them, complaining.*

Comment: @TinfoilHat As shown in both NYT and WP examples, commas are not required but only optional in [7] iii b. A comma is required, for example, in _They are complaining, all five of them._